# JavaScript slider only works on one computer?

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I've just set up the ideal image slider for my site and for some reason its only working on the computer I designed it on, whenever I look at it on a different device I loose my navigation buttons. I can't understand why as both devices are reading the page with chrome.

Can anyone work out why this issue is occurring?

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/ideal-image-slider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/default.css">      
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Image Slider</h1>

    <div id="slider">
        <img src="IMAGES/img01.jpg">
        <img data-src="IMAGES/img02.jpg" src="IMAGES/img02.jpg">
        <img data-src="IMAGES/img03.jpg" src="IMAGES/img03.jpg">
        <img data-src="IMAGES/img04.jpg" src="IMAGES/img04.jpg">
        <img data-src="IMAGES/img05.jpg" src="IMAGES/img05.jpg">
        <img data-src="IMAGES/img06.jpg" src="IMAGES/img06.jpg">
        <img data-src="IMAGES/img07.jpg" src="IMAGES/img07.jpg">
        <img data-src="IMAGES/img08.jpg" src="IMAGES/img08.jpg">
        <img data-src="IMAGES/img09.jpg" src="IMAGES/img09.jpg">
        <img data-src="IMAGES/img10.jpg" src="IMAGES/img10.jpg">
    </div>
    <script src="ideal-image-slider.js"></script>
    <script>
        new IdealImageSlider.Slider('#slider');
    </script>

    <form action="edit.php">
        <input type="submit" class="btnEdit" value="EDIT" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Slider Code is here as it is too long to post:
server2.sulmaxcp.com/ideal-image-slider.js

Comment: Where is the code for `IdealImageSlider`?

Comment: `new IdealImageSlider.Slider('#slider');` doesn't seem right. It seems like you should be storing the object reference with a variable, as in `var slide = new IdealImageSlider.Slider('#slider');`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for commenting I've added a link to the slider code as it was too long to post.

Comment: Please don't add links to code. Post the code right here in your question to make it easier for us to answer.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference if you store the varaible or not, that is only if you want to do something with it. If it's working on one device it works. How are you trying on other devices, are you hosting this somewhere?